# Editing and Updating an ADF Pivot table

Tags: oracle-adf

I have created an ADF Pivot table; but, I am not able to update the table.

Can anyone please help me out on how to make an updatable ADF Pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the ADF Faces Components demo (you can download the source from oracle.com/ADF->Download tab)
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/pivotTable/pivotTableEdit.jspx

Note that you'll need to handle the actual update to the database in your own code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shay